# "this" keyword in global space and inside function in Node.js environment

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
console.log(this)       // {}
function abc(){
    console.log(this)
}
abc()                  // global
```

The value of **this** in global space and inside function is different in Node.js environment.

```
console.log(this === module.exports)  // true
function abc(){
    console.log(this === global)
}
abc()                                 // true
```

Since, **this** represents the context/object in which the function is called, and the **this** in global space refers to **global object**. So, the value of **this** should have been **global object** right?
This is correct in the browser, but why not in case of Node.js environment?

Comment: One should not use `this` in those contexts, anyway.

Comment: You see that place in the question where it says "enter image description here". How about actually doing that?

Comment: "*the this in global space refers to global object.*" - maybe, but your nodejs code is not actually executing in global space, but in module space.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the value of `this` can be different in the global scope and inside a function in Node.js, and that this can be confusing. Here's why:

In the global scope:

- In non-strict mode, when you call a function without any context (e.g., `myFunction()`), `this` will default to the global object. In Node.js, the global object is similar to the `window` object in a browser, but it doesn't have the same properties and methods.
- In strict mode (`"use strict";`), `this` will be `undefined` when called in the global scope.

Inside a function:

- The value of `this` depends on how the function is called. Here are some common cases:

  - Regular function call: If you call a function directly, `this` will be the global object (in non-strict mode) or `undefined` (in strict mode).
  - Method call: If you call a function as a method of an object, `this` will be that object.
  - Constructor call: When you use the `new` keyword to create a new object, `this` will be the newly created object.
  - `call`, `apply`, or `bind`: You can use these methods to explicitly set the value of `this` when calling a function.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding the behavior of `this` in different contexts, especially in the Node.js environment, can indeed be a bit tricky due to how it differs from browser JavaScript. Let's break down your observations to clarify these concepts.

Global Context in Node.js

When you reference `this` at the top level in a Node.js module, it doesn't refer to the global object (`global`), as it would in a browser environment (where it refers to `window`). Instead, it refers to `module.exports`, which is the object that will be exported from the module. This is why `console.log(this === module.exports)` outputs `true`. In Node.js, each file is treated as a module, and the top-level `this` value is set to the exports of the module to facilitate module exports.

#### Function Context in Node.js

When you declare a function and then call it without attaching it to an object, JavaScript sets the context (`this`) to the global object. However, in strict mode (which is recommended for use in modern JavaScript), `this` will be `undefined` inside functions that are called in such a "standalone" manner, unless the function is called as a method of an object, in which case `this` is set to the object the method is called on.

Node.js modules are wrapped in a function that provides module-specific variables like `module`, `exports`, `require`, etc. This wrapping function is not called on any object, so its `this` value is set to `exports` by default. However, when you declare a function inside a Node.js module and then call it directly (not as a method of an object), `this` defaults to the global object, which is why `console.log(this === global)` inside a function outputs `true`.

#### Summary

- **Global Scope (`this === module.exports`)**: In the global scope of a Node.js module, `this` refers to `module.exports` because the code is executed in the context of the module's exports.
- **Inside a Function (`this === global`)**: Inside a function that is not called as a method of an object, `this` refers to the global object. This is because the function inherits the global scope when it is not bound to any other object.

This distinction helps in modularizing the code in Node.js, by keeping the top-level `this` scoped to the module rather than the global object, which can help prevent accidental pollution of the global namespace. Understanding these nuances is crucial for effective Node.js development and leveraging JavaScript's flexible context assignment to its full potential.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the behavior of `this` in the Node.js environment, it's essential to differentiate between how `this` behaves in the global scope versus inside functions, and how it contrasts with its behavior in a browser environment.

In the Node.js environment:

- **In the global scope**, `this` refers to `module.exports` for the current module. The Node.js runtime wraps each module's code inside a function before executing it. This wrapper function, not visible in the source code, provides module-specific variables like `exports`, `require`, `module`, `__filename`, and `__dirname`. The `this` value at the top level of a module points to `exports` of the module because that's the context in which the module's code is executed. When you do `console.log(this)`, it shows `{}` initially because `module.exports` is an empty object by default, which you haven't modified yet.
- **Inside a function**, when you call a function like `abc()` directly, without attaching it to an object or using call/apply/bind methods, `this` defaults to the global object. In a browser, the global object is `window`, but in Node.js, it's `global`. This behavior leads to the observed output where `console.log(this === global)` inside a function returns `true`. This is because Node.js functions, when called in such a manner, have their `this` context set to the global object, which is `global` in Node.js.

In contrast, in the browser environment:

- **In the global scope**, `this` refers to the `window` object, which is the global object in browsers. This is why, in a browser, if you were to execute `console.log(this)` at the top level (outside any function), it would print the `window` object.
- **Inside a function**, if the function is called in the global scope (i.e., not as a method of an object), `this` also refers to the `window` object, unless the function is in strict mode. In strict mode, `this` will be `undefined` inside a function if it's not explicitly set, showing a key difference in how strict mode affects the default binding of `this`.

To summarize, in Node.js:

- At the top level of a module, `this` is equivalent to `module.exports` because of how Node.js executes module code within a module-specific function wrapper.
- Inside a regular function called in the global scope, `this` defaults to the global object (`global`), which differs from the top-level `this`.

Understanding this distinction helps clarify why `this` behaves differently in Node.js compared to the browser, highlighting the impact of the execution context (global scope vs. inside a function) and the environment (Node.js vs. browser) on the value of `this`.